# Close process in NSIS script during install

Tags: process, nsis

I plug `nsProcess` to close a running program but when I close it, a message will appear stating "Are you sure? OK - Cancel".

How can I automatically, during installation, chose option "Yes", without direct user intervention?

```
$ {nsProcess :: CloseProcess} "yahoomessanger.exe" $ R0
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`nsProcess::CloseProcess` tries to be nice and posts WM_CLOSE to the application, use `nsProcess::KillProcess` to kill it without giving the app a chance to close properly...

Comment: This command does not cause the closure of the program !!! nsProcess::KillProcess

Comment: I looked at the source code and those two codepaths are very similar. If you believe it does not work then you could report it to the plugin author but it looked correct to me...